# MATLAB int32 overflows at 18th bit

Tags: matlab, signed, integer-overflow

I'm trying to simulate 32-bit signed integer arithmetics with MATLAB. The int32 function does not behave as expected:

```
accu = 0
inc = 40000
accu = int32(accu + inc)
accu = int32(accu + inc)
accu = int32(accu + inc)
accu = int32(accu + inc)
```

The values of accu after the respective additions are 40000, 80000, 120000 and then -102144. I expected 160000 and not a negative number since the overflow is supposed to occur only on the 32nd bit, not on the 18th.

Oddly enough,

```
int32(120000 + 40000)
```

gives 160000 as expected. How can I force int32 operations when using variables as above?

---

EDIT: I'm adding a screenshot of exactly what I'm doing since some people cannot reproduce the behavior.

[image: screenshot]

Comment: MATLAB’s integer operations do not overflow. It uses saturated arithmetic.

Comment: @CrisLuengo: I want 32 bit signed integer arithmetics, that's why I'm using the int32 function to do the overflow for me when the argument is greater than 2^32. But it overflows at 2^18. Why?

Comment: @travelboy I can't reproduce. Your first snippet gives `160000` for me (R2019a, WIndows 10)

Comment: I cannot reproduce, 2017b

Comment: I am using R2019b Update 2 on MacOS. Will post a screenshot.

Comment: Type `which int32` to make sure you didn’t shadow it. Your result is unlikely.

Comment: As I said, MATLAB doesn’t overflow, it saturates. If you want overflow you will have to simulate it.

Comment: @CrisLuengo `which int32` ->
`built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2019b.app/toolbox/matlab/datatypes/int32)`

Comment: Your results make no sense. I’m out of ideas. I doubt this is a bug, but have no other explanation right now. Consider contacting the MathWorks.

Comment: Cannot reproduce it neither, 2018b Windows.

Comment: Re-cap: **1)** Several people agree the code should return 160000 and not a negative number. **2)** Several people were unable to reproduce this with various versions of MATLAB under Windows. **3)** The code will not perform the desired overflow due to saturated arithmetics, but regardless of that, the behavior is unexpected. It would be great if someone could try this on a Mac. Otherwise I will contact MathWorks.

Comment: Bizarre. I cannot reproduce on R2019a or R2019b on macOS 10.14.6; I also get `160000` for the last operation. I have no theory as to what could produce the behavior you're seeing. I suggest you try R2019a and R2018b on your same machine, and then contact MathWorks support.

Comment: BTW, you don't need the `int32(...)` calls on every add operation. Just initialize `accu = int32(0)`. In Matlab, mixed-mode arithmetic narrows doubles to ints, instead of widening ints to doubles like most other languages do.

Comment: R2016a/Win10 - I cannot reproduce, I get `160000`. However, I noticed that the binary representation of both `160000` and `-102144` have their two LSBytes identical (`[113 0]`), and the 2 MSbytes are kind of _inverted_. The 2 MSB of `160000` (`[0 2]`) yield the value `2` if cast to an `int16`, while the 2 MSB of `-102144` (`[255 244]`) yield the value `-2` if cast to an `int16`. Not sure what it means but it could point you to the problems ...

Comment: Any 3rd party binaries (mex or s function) in use? If so remove them from the search path and restart matlab.

Comment: I found the problem! A folder had been in the path in which a file overloaded the plus operator for int32 types. So MATLAB still used the built-in type, but instead of the built-in addition performed a different one which lead to this effect.

Answer (score 1):

A folder had been in the path in which a file overloaded the plus operator for int32 types. So MATLAB still used the built-in type, but instead of the built-in addition performed a different one which lead to this effect.